# Editing (or live-refreshing) a post that you follow resets the text of the Follow button

Tags: bug, status-review, edits, user-interface, follow-post

I followed a question, then started editing it. After I saved the edits, it returned to the post (as usual) but I noticed that the text of the Follow button has been reset to "Follow" instead of "Following". I thought maybe I hadn't actually followed it but upon refreshing the page, the button said "Following" as it did prior to the edit.

I initially assumed that for this to happen, you have to start editing the post before refreshing the page. Turns out, that doesn't matter. The text will be reset even if the post has already been followed before you open the Q&A page.

This most likely only happens with the inline editor (i.e., you must have 2k+ rep to test this).

It looks like the same thing happens if you live-refresh the post (e.g. if someone else edits the post while you have it open).

Comment: I can confirm that I'm able to reproduce this behavior as well. Does this also happen if someone else edits the post, and you "live-refresh" it (by clicking the "An edit has been made to this post" message that appears at the top of the post)?

Comment: A potentially related bug report: [Inline tag editor disappears after live refreshing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382180/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast I actually tried to test that when I was looking for more connections between the two bugs. However, this is not easy to test because you have to open a new question (for a higher possibility that it'll get edited), follow it, and wait for an edit to come. To make matters worse, live refresh seems to stop randomly (at least for me). I even tried to edit the question myself on another tab but I still didn't get the "An edit has been made" message.

Comment: @V2Blast I just managed to catch it and it does indeed reset the text of the button after live refresh.