# Inline tag editor disappears after live refreshing a question

Tags: bug, status-review, live-refresh, inline-tag-editor

The inline tag editor unlocked with [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) allows for quick and convenient editing of tags.

However, recently the editor link disappears after a live refresh of the question requiring the page to be reloaded to be back. See demonstration:

[image: Demonstration of the described bug: a question which was edited shows the "Edit tags" link but after clicking on the body of the question to live refresh it, the "Edit tags" link disappears.]

Furthermore, after the refresh pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>T</kbd> for the inline tag editor does not open it, either.

This *used to* happen only if after the live refresh there would be a pending suggested edit on the post. That is not the case here - you can see "Edit" does not change to "Edit (1)" to indicate a pending edit.

I do not know when exactly this bug started happening. All I know is that it is fairly recent. It presents a problem when trying to edit the tags of a question which received an edit.

Comment: It also disappears after editing the question using the inline editor (not inline _tag_ editor). This is closely related to this recent bug report of mine: [Editing a post that you follow resets the text of the Follow button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380954/348196). They both likely have the same root cause.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I've noticed the "Follow" button change to the wrong status occasionally but this is new. I'm not sure if they are related. Could be but if so, it indicates something was broken even more than before.

Comment: Clicking the post after getting the "an edit has been made" message uses JavaScript to update the post's view without actually reloading the page (i.e., re-navigating to it). That's also exactly what happens with the inline editor, which is why I suspect both "glitches" have the same root cause.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm seeing this behavior as well.