# When a question is edited, and you're currently viewing the question, the tags disappear

Tags: bug, tags, edits, live-refresh

*Note: I'm unsure if this is specific to Stack Overflow only or not.*

If one is currently viewing a question, and then the question gets edited by *someone else*, the tags disappear.

As you can see in this picture, there are no tags:

[image]

You need to reload the page in order to view the tags.

This also used to happen to me when I would use the "inline tag editor" (awarded at 10k). But I couldn't just reproduce it.

*This happened to me a few times, hence this post.*

If it matters:

- I do have multiple browser extensions installed.
- macOS.
- Chrome Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (arm64).

Comment: I just clicked the banner that said that edits have been made when you edited _this_ question. Are those the conditions which resulted in the bug? For me the tags were still present.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Ah, ok, interesting. so maybe it's only for Stack Overflow? or can just happen sometimes?

Comment: Not sure, it could also be a browser-specific issue or maybe something to do with extensions you have installed. Although I didn't see the issue here and I also have macos and Chrome.

Comment: Just editing any question then clicking done gives a page with no tags until reload. (SO Firefox)

Comment: Yup. The same in Firefox (currently 108.0.1. [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript), with minimum JavaScript allowed).  It has been like that for the past few weeks (or months?). Good luck getting it fixed. It is weird they don't have regression tests to catch [breaking stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_Platforms#History). Though [YouTube is far worse](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/22/bold-and-italics-in-youtube-comments/#YouTube_breaks_stuff).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this bug has been previously reported as well...

Comment: @V2Blast you're likely remembering [this related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382180/inline-tag-editor-disappears-after-live-refreshing-a-question).

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: Ah, yep, that's the one I was thinking of.